# Don't raise a closed-without-comment flag for migrations

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, flags, migration, moderator-tools

When we migrated [this question on SR](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23434/powerpoint-2010-alignment-issue?noredirect=1) ([timeline, mod-only](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/timeline/23434)) to another site, Community raised a "closed w/o comment (auto)" flag. There are two aspects to this:

1. I finally got to decline a flag with a fun custom message using the word "stoooopid" (good)
2. This is bad, because I'm not going to leave a comment on a migration stub left on my site (bad).

Please fix this, I wasted like three seconds declining that flag.

Comment: "I finally got to decline a flag with a fun custom message using the word "stoooopid" (good)" Why you gotta be so harsh to Community? What has it ever done to you except help clean up your site and hold on to things (like votes) other people have left behind? :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given migration *involves* closing the question, this isn't a bug - if you migrate without first commenting, then you are indeed closing without comment.

Those auto-flags [could use some love](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239585/turn-the-closed-without-comment-flag-into-a-queue) - but for the time being, they're a simple and reasonably effective way to remind folks on small sites to provide feedback to those who might help them grow if carefully guided.

Comment: I'd argue that it's not closing from the user's point of view - their question is still open, albeit in a different place. Although it makes sense that it's technically a closure... Seems suboptimal, as you say.

Comment: If the migration is rejected, then it's just closed. With no explanation.

Comment: That's a good point, hadn't thought of that.